# Can't compile matplotlib on Ubuntu 11.04 / ft2build.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 11.04, xorg, python, wayland, x11

I'm trying to build [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) from source but it isn't working. It seems this thing was a part of X11, and since Ubuntu is now using Wayland that screwed things up, I think.

Anyway to fix this?

Oh, ok. I just had to install `libfreetype6` and `libfreetype6-dev` with apt-get. I can't answer it now so I'll edit it later or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found these dependencies in the install file:

```
  matplotlib core: zlib, zlib-devel, libpng, libpng-devel,
                   freetype, freetype-devel, freetype-utils

  gtk backend: gtk2-devel, gtk+-devel, pygtk2, glib-devel,
               pygtk2-devel, gnome-libs-devel, pygtk2-libglade

  tk backend: tcl, tk, tkinter
```

Do you have all those installed?

Comment: I have now! Truth be told I realized now that they tell you in the matplotlib page that you need libpng and freetype but I guess I just skipped that part. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 3):

I should install `libfreetype-dev` (Ubuntu).

Comment: OP has already clarified in an edit that the issue is solved: *Oh, ok. I just had to install libfreetype6 and libfreetype6-dev with apt-get.*

Comment: I had the same problem when compiling `php-7.1.12` on **CentOS-7**, I did `/usr/include/freetype2` and every thing went OK.

Answer (score 1):

For RHEL use below command :

```
yum install freetype-devel -y
```

For Ubuntu use below command:

```
apt-get install libfreetype-dev -y
```